# Content as HTML vs as XML to publish

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a website with lot of content which is being grabbed from sql database in xml format. I am using XML publish method in asp.net to publish all the content through menu's. Now we are having a debate should we use HTML to display content? Can someone give me good and bad points about using one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML uses semantics that browsers, screen readers, search engines and new people joining your project know about. Your own XML application doesn't.

Deliver HTML to browsers.

If you are designing a web based API, then arbitrary XML is a decent choice (unless there is a preexisting XML application that already covers your use case (or even, thanks to namespaces, part of it)).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you to use **XSLT** to render the **XML** through the **.net controls** and display the content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you serve the content in XML, be aware that Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support files served that way.

http://www.w3.org/International/articles/serving-xhtml/Overview.en

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20020801/